# Springboot Security: Passwords do not match during login

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, encryption

I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder in order to encrypt a users registration and login.

The registration part works fine, it puts a new user into the database with a password such as:

```
 '$2a$10$aUk/26idLhSaNmhNRTRejd03FnxxLxv6X0Uo0P4PcA4mbyy.
```

When I come to login, the username entered matches and I successfully find a user from the repository.

I am then told that the username or password is wrong. When I remove this encryption away from the program it works fine. So essentially I am doing something wrong when comparing the encrypted passwords.

Here is my UserDetailsService implementation logic:

```
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        System.out.println(username);

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        if (user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "No user found with username: "+ username);
        }
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        return  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                (user.getUsername(),
                        user.getPassword().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired,
                        credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                        getAuthorities(Arrays.asList("ROLE_USER")));
    }

    private static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities (List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
```

I also set up the beans in the web security file:

```
  @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where in your code are you comparing the submitted password to the stored hash? Did you make sure you're passing the same salt to BCrypt when you compare as you did when you hashed it in the first place?

Comment: why are you doing this: `user.getPassword().toLowerCase()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have a non-default configuration set up, the BCryptPasswordEncoder should be saving your users passwords to the database encrypted (which it looks to be functioning properly). You shouldn't be calling `#toLowerCase()` on an encrypted password since it completely changes the encryption.

The code posted doesn't appear to do any comparison.

If you are using a manual means of checking if the passwords match, you should instead use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches` [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/apidocs/). It takes a non-encrypted password and then a salted hash (encrypted password) and then tells you if they are equals via a boolean return value.

Comment: Ahh. Yes i should not have put that in. Thanks.